# Concept of ADO.NET classes object binding with SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, ado.net, code-behind

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("user_storedproc_name", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[14];
        parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@p1", vlaue);
        String ts = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value1)?"0":value1;
        parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("p2", Convert.ToInt64(ts));
        parameters[2] = new SqlParameter("p3", value3);
        String strDate1 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value4)? "01/01/1900":value4;
        parameters[3] = new SqlParameter("@p4", ConvertDate(strDate1).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"));
        String strDate2 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value5)? "01/01/1900":value5;
        parameters[4] = new SqlParameter("@p5", ConvertDate(strDate2).ToShortDateString());
        parameters[5] = new SqlParameter("@p6", value6);
        String strDate3 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value7)? "01/01/1900":value7;
        parameters[6] = new SqlParameter("@p7", ConvertDate(strDate3).ToShortDateString());
        String strDate4 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value8)? "01/01/1900":value8;
        parameters[7] = new SqlParameter("@p8", ConvertDate(strDate4).ToShortDateString());
        parameters[8] = new SqlParameter("@p9", value9);
        parameters[9] = new SqlParameter("@p10", value10);
        parameters[10] = new SqlParameter("@p11", value11);
        parameters[11] = new SqlParameter("@p12", value12);
        String strDate5 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value13)?"01/01/1900":value13;
        parameters[12] = new SqlParameter("@p13", ConvertDate(strDate5).ToShortDateString());
        string strp14val = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(value14)) ? "0" : value14;
        parameters[13] = new SqlParameter("@p14",DbType.Int32);
        parameters[13].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        int r_retval = SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(SQLHelper.GetConnString(), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "user_storedproc_name", "DB_NAME_STRING", parameters);

private DateTime ConvertDate(String date)
{
    String str = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        if (date.Contains("/") || date.Contains("-"))
        {
            str = date.Split('/')[2] + "-" + date.Split('/')[1] + "-" + date.Split('/')[0];
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return Convert.ToDateTime(str);
}
```

Code behind throwing error nvarchar to datetime.

Note: This working fine with `SqlCommand` object and adding parameters with binding values. but the calling function was `sqlParameter[]` (parameters array) but the `SqlCommand` object parameters is a `SqlParameterCollection`. I spent almost 48 hours of time till now debugging and troubleshooting with no fair success. Throw some light, Something that my sight is not able to get in code that is wrong. awaiting for comments/answers what is possible to guide.

Note: Stored procedure is working fine

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_StoredProc]  
(@p1 nvarchar(500)  
,@p2 nvarchar(50)=null  
,@p3 bigint=null  
,@p4 nvarchar(50)=null  
,@p5 nvarchar(50)=null  
,@p6 varchar(40)=null  
,@p7 nvarchar(50)=null
,@p8 nvarchar(50)=null
,@p9 nvarchar(50)=null 
,@p10 nvarchar(50)=null  
,@p11 nvarchar(50)=null
,@p12 nvarchar(50)=null
,@p13 nvarchar(50)=null
,@p14 int OUTPUT)
AS  
--DECLARE @USP_PROJECT_ID INT
BEGIN
IF (@p14=0)
--print 'enter'
SET dateformat 'dmy';
 INSERT INTO Project_Details
 (col1
 ,col2
 ,col3
 ,col4
 ,col5  
 ,col6
 ,col7
 ,col8
 ,col9
 ,col10
 ,col11
 ,col12
 ,col13)   
 VALUES(@p1
 ,@p2
 ,@p3
 ,Convert(Datetime,@p4,103)
 ,Convert(Datetime,@p5,103)
 ,@p6
 ,Convert(Datetime,@p7,103)  
 ,Convert(Datetime,@p8,103)
 ,@p9
 ,@p10
 ,@p11
 ,@p12
 ,@p13)
-- print SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 SET @p13=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 SELECT Project_Details.Project_Id FROM Project_Details WHERE Project_Id=@Project_id
END
```

Comment: Is there any reason, you are passing dates as strings and not as `DateTime` into the sproc? Apart from that. Where excactly is your error occuring. Since you are converting left and right, there is no way to tell where your code is failing.

Comment: @Marco 1 Passing strings need not to be formatted before assigning to SqlParameter. This is the reason that my stored procedure convert to DateTime at the time of Insert statement execution. hope  this helps in reproducing error and resolving the issue asap.

Comment: No they must not. You are converting them back to DateTime in the insert statement, so you can pass them in as valid Date objects from the calling C# code. There is no need to convert them. And if you do not convert them, there is no possibility for you Sproc to throw a conversion error.

Comment: @Marco Really good suggestion to follow. Actually I took DateTime in SProc earlier but it was not working. I was suggested to change for string type and convert it later that worked. Thanks a lot you saved my time of further debugging same code. As of now issue resolved.

Comment: Change your stored procedure to accept `datetime` instead of `varchar`

Comment: @Charlieface Seems right approach is to do as you suggested. this is helpful. +10 to you for appropriate comment that could take me to solution

Comment: Try this Nuget library : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ado.Entity/